# Passenger 'ps' malware detection

Tags: passenger

We are seeing what I believe is a false positive from an endpoint protection product.  We see passengeragent kick off 'ps -p  -o ucomm=' .  It appears that it's just a heartbeat of some sort.  Can anyone confirm whether this is expected behavior?

Comment: This is Phusion Passenger(R) 6.0.12 on a fully patched Debian server.

Comment: Also, command got munged a bit, it's 'ps -p # -o ucomm=' where # is the pid of the passengeragent instance that spawned bash->ps.